# Java - BufferOverflowException when trying to write to a file 2 or more times

Tags: java, file, exception, byte, bytebuffer

I am trying to write a program that can take 1 bit at a time and then write 2 bytes to a file once 16 bits have been "collected".

Here is the basic code:

```
public void addBit(int bit) throws IOException{
    if(this.byteholder.length() < 16){
        this.byteholder += "" + bit;
    }
    else{
        write();
    }
}

public void write() throws IOException{
    if(this.byteholder.length() == 16){
        System.out.println(this.byteholder);
        int a = Integer.parseInt(byteholder, 2);
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(a));
        ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putInt(a);
        byte[] byteArray = bytes.array();

        out.write(byteArray);
        out.flush();
        this.byteholder = "";
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File f = new File("test");
        BitFileWriter out = new BitFileWriter(f);
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
            out.addBit(1);
            out.addBit(0);
            out.addBit(0);
            out.addBit(1);
            out.addBit(0);
            out.addBit(1);
            out.addBit(1);
            out.addBit(0);
            out.addBit(1);
            out.addBit(0);
            out.addBit(0);
            out.addBit(1);
            out.addBit(0);
            out.addBit(1);
            out.addBit(1);
            out.addBit(0);
        }

        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

main method is just used for testing the methods above. The "out" variable is a FileOutputStream, "byteholder" is a String that holds the binary code and the file "test" is a random empty file I have in my Eclipse project directory.

The problem I am getting is that if I run my test code more than once (loop the addbit code more than once) I get a BufferOverflowException and I have no idea why. I am not sure of how to properly use a ByteBuffer but I needed it to be able to write 2 bytes to the file at a time. Can anybody help? Thanks.

Also BONUS question! Whenever I sucessfully run my test code I can see that the file size in my "test" file is unchanged (still says 0 bytes). Why?. I am running Windows 10 btw.

EDIT:
Here is my stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferOverflowException
at java.nio.Buffer.nextPutIndex(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.putInt(Unknown Source)
at CompPck.BitFileWriter.write(BitFileWriter.java:30)
at CompPck.BitFileWriter.addBit(BitFileWriter.java:21)
at CompPck.BitFileWriter.main(BitFileWriter.java:66)
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: @SteveSmith Oops, thanks for reminding me. I posted the stack trace now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putInt(a);`

You're allocating 2 bytes for an int which is 4 bytes. What do you expect to happen? Use `short` (and `putShort`) if you want to use 16-bit values.

If you're getting problems with using short due to signedness problems (`1001011010010110` is considered to exceed the value of short), you can keep your `a` as `int`, but write the value with `putShort((short)a)`.

As for your file staying empty, you're probably not closing resources properly in your `close()` method, or you're forgetting to write *your* buffer to the file.

Comment: Before I tried using an Int I did try to use a Short. However when I used a a Short I got a "NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"1001011010010110" Radix:2" error. Any idea why?

Comment: See my edit. You can keep using an `int`, but write it to the buffer as a `short`.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it! Just a small little question... I am quite new to Java (and programming in general). What is supposed to be written to my file exactly? What is my file supposed to show? Right now it only shows 2 lines like so: "--" (without quotation marks ofc). File size now shows 2 bytes so I guess I did that right...

Comment: It shows the bits you wrote into the file, interpreted as single byte characters. If you print out `Integer.toBinaryString('-')` you  should see the original bit pattern you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

As to why your output file stays empty:

The first time you call your `write()` method is at the moment that you try to add the 17th bit (and loose it btw).

If you do only one iteration (i.e. only try to write 16 bits) your write method is never called. Therefore the `BufferOverflowException` does not show up - but also nothing is ever written to the file.

Comment: Ah thanks fixed that part now. Still keep getting the BufferOverflowException though...

Comment: Nvm It is now fixed! :)